# Unipotent characters of (disconnected) centralizers of semisimple elements: Why these two definitions are equivalent?

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, reductive-groups

Assume that $\mathcal{G}$ is a simple simply-connected algebraic group over $k$, where $k$ is algebraic closure of a finite field of characteristic $p>0$, and $F$ is a Frobenius endomorphism. Let $(\mathcal{G^*}, F^*)$ be dual to $(\mathcal{G}, F)$ and $s$ be a semisimple element of group of fixed points  $G^*:=\mathcal{G^*}^{F^*}$. Then $C_{\mathcal{G^*}}(s)$ is not necessarily connected. We need some arguments in order to extend the definition of unipotent characters to the disconnected group $C_{G^*}(s)$  . 
 Definition #1:
It is known that $C_{G^*}(s)/C_{G^*}^{o}(s)$ acts on the set of unipotent characters of $C_{G^*}^{o}(s)$ (see for instance, Theorem 15.13 and its corollary in Representation Theory of Finite Reductive Groups by M. Cabanes and M. Enguehard). Hence, for $\rho \in \mathrm{Irr}(C_{G^*}(s))$, if $\mathrm{Res}_{C_{G^*}^{o}(s)}^{C_{G^*}(s)}(\rho)$ contains a unipotent character of $C_{G^*}^{o}(s)$, then $\mathrm{Res}_{C_{G^*}^{o}(s)}^{C_{G^*}(s)}(\rho)$ is sum of unipotent characters of $C_{G^*}^{o}(s)$. Such $\rho$'s are defined to be unipotent characters of $C_{G^*}(s)$ (see for instance Sec. 5 of F. Digne and J. Michel, Groupes reductifs non connexes, Ann. Scient. Ec. Norm. Sup (1994) 345 - 406).
Definition #2:
 Some papers in the literature (for instance: G. Malle, Height 0 characters of finite groups of Lie type, Represent. Theory (2007) 192-220), use another definition for unipotent characters of $C_{G^*}(s)$:
$\rho \in \mathrm{Irr}(C_{G^*}(s))$ is called unipotent if its restriction to the connected component $C_{G^*}^{o}(s)$ is unipotent.
Question:
Clearly Definition #2 assumed something more: unipotent characters of $C_{G^*}^{o}(s)$ are $C_{G^*}(s)$-invariant. But I can't see why this assumption satisfied? Why these two definitions are the same?
Thank you in advance for any enlightening comment. Also I apologize in advance if the question seems not appropriate for MO. Since my questions about Deligne-Lusztig theory (like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1931143/on-the-existence-of-semisimple-irreducible-characters-of-simply-connected-alge)) didn't get any answer in M.SE, I decided to post them here to get an answer.

Comment: I think the problem is terminology. What I assume Malle means by unipotent is that it is a sum of unipotent characters of $C_{G^{\star}}^{\circ}(s)$. It's not true that a unipotent character of $C_{G^{\star}}(s)$ necessarily restricts irreducibly to $C_{G^{\star}}^{\circ}(s)$. Is this what you're worried is implied?

Comment: @JayTaylor Yes, this is exactly what I'm worried about. And the the exact sentence of Malle's paper (pp. 194) is: "...By definition, $\mathcal{E}(C_{G^*}(s), 1)$ consists of the irreducible characters of $C_{G^*}(s)$ whose restriction to the connected component $C_{G^*}^{o}(s)$ is unipotent".

Comment: @JayTaylor Is it known in general that for which finite groups of Lie type, the unipotent characters of disconnected centralizers (of semisimple elements) are extensions of the unipotent characters of their connected components?  I will appreciate it if you could provide an example of such a centralizer whose unipotent characters are not necessarily an extension of  unipotent characters of the connected component, or refer me to some references.

Comment: Well, you need to understand how automorphisms act on unipotent characters of connected groups. This is discussed in several places but you could look at the first chapter of my thesis, link: https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-00709051/document. I needed to use these types of things there. Check out Proposition 1.51, for instance. You could also look at Example 1.76, this is an example of the behaviour you're looking for.

Comment: @JayTaylor Oh! I am truly grateful for your comments, and also for the reference you provided. That's exactly what I am looking for to know. Thanks a lot.